# If/Else logic in Blaze causing authenticated user page flickers when navigating between pages in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I have this main layout

```
<!-- Wrapper-->
<div id="wrapper">
    {{#if currentUser }}

     <!-- Page wrapper -->
     {{> topNavbar }}

    <!-- Navigation -->
      {{> navigation }}

      <!-- Page wraper -->
      <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">

          <!-- Main view  -->
          {{> yield}}
      </div>
      <!-- End page wrapper-->
      <!--{{> rightSidebar }}-->

    {{else}}
      {{> loginPage }}

    {{/if}}
</div>
<!-- End wrapper-->
```

With the obvious purpose of displaying the login page if users are not logged-in.  An unintended effect is when users navigate between certain pages/routes it can occasionally show the loginpage for a half second or two.

I am sure there is a way to do this with subscriptions, but just haven't gotten their in Meteor yet... was wondering if one of the ninjas out there that will look at this and scoff can pass a quick hint.

Thanks!

I have seen [How to get rid of Meteor template flickers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305666/how-to-get-rid-of-meteor-template-flickers) but I am hoping that there is a way to solve this without routing -- can I add the code to the main templates javascript file?

Comment: my guess it's flickering because there is no `Meteor.user()` available right away. If you use meteorhacks's package `fast-render` it makes it available instantly and should stop the flickering. Without fast-render you can also listen check if the user is not `loggingIn` and only after you have the data to check if there is a user.

Comment: maybe you can put a waitOn on client side and subscribe with `return Meteor.user();`? then also you can configure router to display a loading template while waiting for subscribe data

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, there are not two states of logged in and not. There is also the in between state where the client is logging in. To account for that, there is a `{{loggingIn}}` helper which you could use as:

```
<!-- Wrapper-->
<div id="wrapper">
    {{#if currentUser }}

     <!-- Page wrapper -->
     {{> topNavbar }}

    <!-- Navigation -->
      {{> navigation }}

      <!-- Page wraper -->
      <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">

          <!-- Main view  -->
          {{> yield}}
      </div>
      <!-- End page wrapper-->
      <!--{{> rightSidebar }}-->

    {{else}}

      {{#if loggingIn}}

        loading...

      {{else}}

        {{> loginPage }}

      {{/if}}

    {{/if}}
</div>
<!-- End wrapper-->
```

Also on an unrelated note, you can use

```
{{!-- Spacebars comments do not get into the DOM --}}
```

instead of

```
<!-- This still gets into the DOM, but not rendered by the browser -->
```

Comment: Will test this out next week, sorry for delay!